# Can't write params to Model. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I trying write params to Company model. But I have error undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class in this point  = simple_form_for @company, url: update_settings_company_path do |f|. Where I must set @company?

Controller

```
def change_settings    
    @vacation_days = current_company.vacation_days
    @illnes_days = current_company.illnes_days
  end

  def update_settings
    if @company.update(company_params)
      redirect_to account_company_path, notice: t('company.settings_changed')
    else
      render action: 'change_settings'
    end
  end

private
  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:vacation_days, :illnes_days)
  end
```

View

```
.company_settings
  = simple_form_for @company, url: update_settings_company_path do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    = f.input :vacation_days
    = f.input :illnes_days
    %br
    = f.submit t('common.save'), class: 'btn'
    = link_to t('common.back'), account_company_path, class: 'btn'
```

routes

```
resource :company, only: :all do    
    get :change_settings
    post :update_settings
    patch :update_settings
  end
```

What's wrong? Help me please

Comment: I fixed it! In view replaced `@company` with `current_company`. And added `@company = current_company`to update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set `@company` instance variable in both your actions. You can do it using `before_filter`, like this:

```
before_filter :find_company

def change_settings    
  @vacation_days = current_company.vacation_days
  @illnes_days = current_company.illnes_days
end

def update_settings
  if @company.update(company_params)
    redirect_to account_company_path, notice: t('company.settings_changed')
  else
    render action: 'change_settings'
  end
end

private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:vacation_days, :illnes_days)
  end

  def find_company
    @company = current_company
  end
```

Comment: I pasted it to change_settings method
    `def change_settings
    @company = current_company
    @vacation_days = current_company.vacation_days
    @illnes_days = current_company.illnes_days`
But now i get this error undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
`def update_settings
if @company.update(company_params)`

Comment: The error is coming in `update_settings_company_path` so you need to do it in update_settings

Comment: whatever undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: @MaryDear, I edited my asnwer. I also suggest learning some Rails basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, You need to set the instance variable before you use it. By default the instance variable is set to nil.

```
  def update_settings
    @company = current_company
    if @company.update(company_params)
      redirect_to account_company_path, notice: t('company.settings_changed')
    else
      render action: 'change_settings'
    end
  end
```

Comment: It not help. whatever  undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class